# Failing to parse results of the nodejs function to specific varaibles

Tags: node.js

code...needed to pass the first set of results of the function obj to console. It returns nothing

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
var obj = gplay.reviews({appId: 'com'});
var Fieldsomevar = someVar.gplay.reviews[0][0];
console.log(Fieldsomevar);
```

Comment: Reading the documentation is illuminating. https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper  The Usage demonstrates that it works with Promises, rather than as synchronous code.

Comment: New to Nodejs...Not familiar with promises. Reading up on this now...

Comment: I got it! Its all about using the Promises correctly. Thanks Paul